# My text is going under my header?

Tags: html

So I am new to html coding and am trying to just make a simple portfolio and I want it to look nice so I have been looking at tutorial websites online however I did something weird and I don't know what I did. If anyone could help me with this issue that would be great.

Screenshot:

[image]

The Code Is Below (https://pastebin.com/GDCW2jsu):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ryan Cole Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Page Wrapper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">

    <!-- Header -->
                <header id="header">
                    <h1><a href="index.html"><border>Ryan Cole Home</border>
</a></h1>
                    <nav>
                        <a href="about.html">About Me</a>
                        <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                        <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
                    </nav>
                </header>

    <!-- Welcome To The Homepage -->
                <footer>
                <p>Welcome To The Homepage</p>
        </footer>
</body>
</html>
    <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js">
</script><![endif]-->
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be great if you could include the code to your `main.css` and `main.js` as well. It's most likely because of some CSS issue.

Comment: Yes please, do include css and the other related stuff.

Comment: And also let us know how would you like to see it

Comment: It might not fix the positioning of your footer text, but you should remove the first set of closing tags for "body" and "html"' (just under `</footer>`.)

Comment: What output do you want?  I think there's nothing wrong with your code. Please indicate the problem

Comment: all my js files and css files are the HTML5Up files as this was created from a template but I shall put them in a paste bin here

main.css: https://pastebin.com/qphD5Jpg

main.js: https://pastebin.com/Cu8DLDDB

Comment: and @Jonjie I am wanting my text to appear so it isn't under the header because at the moment the header is covering my text and I don't know how to solve it.